# Adding a unique class to wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, menus

How would I go about adding a unique class to the direct child li elements of the main parent ul element generated with wp_nav_menu?

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
  <div class="menu-main-container">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://www.site/page1-2/">Page1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://www.site/sub-page1-1/">Sub-Page1-1</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="http://www.site/sub-page1-2/">Sub-Page1-2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'd like to add the class `menu_element` to `li id="menu-item-30"` and every child li of the parent ul after. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the section titled [Adding Conditional Classes to Menu Items](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_Conditional_Classes_to_Menu_Items) on the `wp_nav_menu` Codex page. This should give you a pretty good overview for adding classes to menu items using the `nav_menu_css_class` filter.

For what you asked to do, which is add `menu_element` to the class attribute for both the menu item with ID 30, and the menu items listed after it, you could do something like this in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function menu_element_class($classes, $item){
    if($item->ID == 30 || $item->menu_item_parent == 30) {
        $classes[] = "menu_element";
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'menu_element_class' , 10 , 2);
```

This just checks to see if the menu item has an ID of 30, or has a menu_item_parent of 30, and adds "menu_element" to the classes array. Of course, you can change the `if` statement to check for whatever conditions you'd like before adding the class.